How do I change this Word-compatible .xml file to open in Word by default?
I am trying to change the labels on a corporate desk phone. The file I've exported from the phone's web interface has the extension .xml, but I need to be able to open it in Microsoft Word in order to modify it.
When I double-click the file, it opens in MS Edge:

If I use Open with... and select Microsoft Word, it shows correctly, like this:

I don't want to change the default handler for XML files on my computer, but I want this file to open in Word when I double-click it.
I know this is a Word-specific format of some sort, because of how it shows correctly when I open it in Word, and so I tried simply changing the extension of the file to .docx, but when I opened the file after doing this Word gave these errors:

Word found unreadable content in label.docx.
Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of this document, Click Yes.

Followed by:

Word experienced an error trying to open the file. Try these suggestions. * Check the file permissions for the document or drive. * Make sure there is sufficient free memory and disk space.

I got the same errors when I renamed the file to an .odt file.
When I tried to zip it and then rename to .docx it gave me these errors:

Question:
What do I need to change this file to in order to make it open in Word just by double-clicking it, and what is the correct method for changing it?

would simply setting .xml documents to open in word be a sufficient solution?

Surely for this file, but in general they should open in Edge or a text editor and not in Word.

so what kind of solution are you looking for?

.docx is an archive of xml files among other file formats. So just renaming a .xml file to .docx isn't going to change it into something Word understands. If Edge is opening up .xml files it simply means you have not associated the file extension with a different application.

it's very easy to check the format, just select "Save As" and it'll show the current format

It sounds like this is working exactly as I would expect - therefore not clear on what you want to change? @FrankThomas  gave you the only clear solution, but you appear to have rejected it.

I think a significant part of the main problem with this post is that you ask one question, but what you really want answered is a different question. You don't actually care "what kind of Word document this file is", you ACTUALLY want to know how to make this file open in Word by default without modifying your computer's default XML handler (which is reasonable). This has little to do with the internal structures of the file as well. I recommend that you EDIT your post to focus on what you truly need here.

Please observe how I have rephrased your question. Your edits made your question less on topic. Based largely on what you selected as the correct answer, I have substantially rewritten your question to focus on the important details and the single, practical question that has been answered by Yorik.

This is a Word document that was saved using "save as..." with the file type "Word XML document"
If you do this with a random document, you will see the same preamble/header, especially:
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
Right click, "open with word" works on a test file.
